# why Property binding not affect on bootstrap model although it have value on page model?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

I work on razor asp.net core 6 . I face issue I can't get value of `blackprintername`  on bootstrap model

`Blackprintername` property binding get value on function `OnGetCheckColors` as blackzebra but on bootstrap model display blank

although I get the values of this property on page model but on razor html not display on input type text `black printer name` .

I execute method type function `OnGetCheckColors` to get  `black printer name` but this not happen so

why value of black printer name not passed .

code details

```
$('#editbootstarp tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    // Get the data from the clicked row
    var rowData = $(this).children('td').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    // Set the values of the modal's input fields

    $('#editshelflabelModal #edit-id').val(rowData[0]);

    $('#editshelflabelModal #edit-Location').val(rowData[6]);

    // Show the modal
    $.ajax({
        url: '?handler=CheckColors',
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            LocationName: rowData[6]
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $('#editshelflabelModal').modal('show');
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    $('#editshelflabelModal').modal('show');
});

public ActionResult OnGetCheckColors(string LocationName) 
{
    List <SubPrinters> subPrintlist = _IAdcSupportService.GetAvailablePrintersLists(HttpContext.Session.GetString("BranchCodesSelected"), LocationName, "SUB");
    if (subPrintlist != null && subPrintlist.Count > 0) 
    {
        foreach(SubPrinters subPrint in subPrintlist) 
        {
            if (subPrint.Category == "Black" && subPrint.IsActive) 
            {
                Blackprintername = subPrint.PrinterName;
                Blackserverip = subPrint.PrinterIP;

            }
        }
    }

    return new JsonResult("success");
}

<div class="modal fade" id="editshelflabelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userDetailsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h5 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;">


            </h5>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editshelflabelModaldata" style="margin-left:200px;">Hi,@TempData["UserID"]</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form id="edit-form" method="post" asp-page-handler="shiftDataUp">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" id="edit-id" name="ShiftId">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edit-server">Server IP</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit-ip" name="serverip">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edit-printer">Printer Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit-printername" name="printername">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edit-locationsdata">Location Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit-Location" name="Location">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="Blackdiv">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h6 class="heading text-darker ml-9" style="margin-top: 12%;">Black Printer</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="form-control-label" for="txtBlackIP">IP Address</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="txtblackip-id" asp-for="Blackserverip" name="blackipdata">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="form-control-label" for="txtBlackName">Printer Shared Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="txtBlackName" value="@Model.Blackprintername" class="form-control">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image for debugging issue as below :

[image: issue not affect bootstrap model]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have a couple of issue in the code. Here are some of them i found on first glance:

1. you don't need to show modal immediately after the ajax call. You need to show it when data arrive. (removed `$('#editshelflabelModal').modal('show');` )
2. Your action result method doesn't return anything except "success" string. You need to build an object and return it
3. Before showing modal, you need to handle incoming data

Here is the fixed snippet

```
$('#editbootstarp tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    // Get the data from the clicked row
    var rowData = $(this).children('td').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    // Set the values of the modal's input fields

    $('#editshelflabelModal #edit-id').val(rowData[0]);
    $('#editshelflabelModal #edit-Location').val(rowData[6]);

    // Show the modal
    $.ajax({
        url: '?handler=CheckColors',
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            LocationName: rowData[6]
        },
        success: function(result) {
            // handle result
            $('#txtBlackName').val(result.Blackprintername);
            $('#txtblackip-id').val(result.Blackserverip);
            $('#editshelflabelModal').modal('show');
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});

public ActionResult OnGetCheckColors(string LocationName) 
{
    List <SubPrinters> subPrintlist = _IAdcSupportService.GetAvailablePrintersLists(HttpContext.Session.GetString("BranchCodesSelected"), LocationName, "SUB");
    if (subPrintlist != null && subPrintlist.Count > 0) 
    {
        foreach(SubPrinters subPrint in subPrintlist) 
        {
            if (subPrint.Category == "Black" && subPrint.IsActive) 
            {
                return Json(new {
                    Blackprintername = subPrint.PrinterName,
                    Blackserverip = subPrint.PrinterIP
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
            }
        }
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```